Cannot access ipv6 but interface has an ipv6 address
My wireless interface has both an ipv4 and an ipv6 address, but I can only ping on ipv4. It looks like the ipv6 neighborhood is empty. Is there a way to restore it? Or is it possible that ipv6 has been disabled somewhere in the network configuration?
R!fedora:/root
> ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:68:4a:2b:fc:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.133.50/24 brd 192.168.133.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 2614sec preferred_lft 2614sec
    inet6 fe80::72c4:6a4f:3b8a:6475/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1354 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet 192.168.253.28 peer 87.190.63.70/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

R!fedora:/root
> ip -6 neigh

R!fedora:/root
> ip -4 neigh
192.168.133.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr d8:0d:17:c0:0f:d3 REACHABLE 

R!fedora:/root
> ip -6 route show
fe80::/64 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium

R!fedora:/root
> sysctl net.ipv6.neigh.default
net.ipv6.neigh.default.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv6.neigh.default.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 128
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 512
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 1024
net.ipv6.neigh.default.interval_probe_time_ms = 5000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.default.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv6.neigh.default.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.default.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.default.unres_qlen = 101
net.ipv6.neigh.default.unres_qlen_bytes = 212992

Here's an attempt to actually access the ipv6 net:
R!fedora:/root
> ping -6 www.google.com
ping: connect: Le réseau n'est pas accessible

R!fedora:/root
> ping -4 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.250.186.68) 56(84) octets de données.
64 octets de fra24s05-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.68) : icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 temps=27.9 ms
64 octets de fra24s05-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.68) : icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 temps=38.8 ms
^C
--- statistiques ping www.google.com ---
2 paquets transmis, 2 reçus, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 27.897/33.339/38.782/5.442 ms


You don't appear to have anything other than a link-local ipv6 address. You're not going to be able to access anything other than other link-local addresses unless you configure a routeable ipv6 address on that interface (e.g., using SLAAC or DHCPv6).

For the future - when posting things online, it's good to use English. Simply run LANG=C ping www.google.com to get everything in English. For better or worse English is the lingua franca of IT.

has IPv6 ever worked? Does your internet provider support IPv6?

In addition to @larsks comment, you will notice link local is given. That should be a hint. If you want to communicate only within your own network, you need to see link Unique local addresses. And if you want to communicate out to the broader internet, then it needs to be link global. See the IPv6 wikipedia page for details.
